# Display one slide at a time in custom HTML slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get my slideshow to present one image at a time. At the moment it shows all the selected images at once; I want one image shown at a time, like in a traditional slideshow with prev/next buttons. I feel like this is really simple and I'm over-thinking things. I've looked at tons of examples but my issue seems to be different from most because in my case the slideshow is different each time -- the images in the slideshow are based off user selected input, therefore the next or previous slide will most likely always be unique, dependent on the topics the user selected.

Anyone have any suggestions? Here is what I have:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#view-content").on("click", function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      if ($('#topic' + i).prop('checked')) {
        $('.topic' + i).show();
      } else {
        $('.topic' + i).hide();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

input[type=checkbox] {}

.topic {
  width: 200px;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
}

.view {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.selectall {
  display: none;
}

.slideshow {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Topics</h1>

<h4>Or choose from popular search terms: </h4>
<div class="row">
  <button type="button">term1</button>
  <button type="button">term2</button>
  <button type="button">term3</button>
  <button type="button">term4</button>
  <button type="button">term5</button>
  <button type="button">term6</button>
  <button type="button">term7</button>
  <button type="button">term8</button>
  <button type="button">term9</button>
  <button type="button">term10</button>
</div>

<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic1" />
      <label for="topic1">Topic 1</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic2" />
      <label for="topic2">Topic 2</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic3" />
      <label for="topic3">Topic 3</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic4" />
      <label for="topic4">Topic 4</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic5" />
      <label for="topic5">Topic 5</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic6" />
      <label for="topic6">Topic 6</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic7" />
      <label for="topic7">Topic 7</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic8" />
      <label for="topic8">Topic 8</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic9" />
      <label for="topic9">Topic 9</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic10" />
      <label for="topic10">Topic 10</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic11" />
      <label for="topic11">Topic 11</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic12" />
      <label for="topic12">Topic 12</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic13" />
      <label for="topic13">Topic 13</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic14" />
      <label for="topic14">Topic 14</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic15" />
      <label for="topic15">Topic 15</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<button type="button" class="view" id="view-content">View Content</button>
<div class="slideshow">
  <img class="topic1 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/Kf2zBCB.jpg" />
  <img class="topic2 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/Sd44gRr.jpg" />
  <img class="topic3 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/5t6Qp5y.jpg" />
  <img class="topic4 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/5vyPC7P.jpg" />
  <img class="topic5 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/H400nzy.jpg" />
  <img class="topic6 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/MXVqtDe.jpg" />
  <img class="topic7 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic8 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic9 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic10 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic11 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic12 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic13 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic14 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic15 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Running this code snippet, then selecting just one or two topics shows just one or two topics when I click 'View Content'. i.e. this code appears to be working as expected.

Comment: @monty Yeah it shows the correct topics but I want it to display one slide at a time. So if I select Topic 1, 2, and 9 when I click "View Content" I want to be shown the Topic 1 slide first and have the user manually move through the slides of Topic 2 and 9 with arrow buttons. At the moment it shows Topic 1, 2, and 9 slides all at once with horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You have a standard slideshow, regardless of the fact that only some images are shown. The markup is still the same -- the only different is `display: none` is applied to some images.

Depending on the type of slideshow you want, you just need to add in some arrows for the user to click on before your first image and after your last image, possibly with pseudo-classes `:before:-first-of-type` and `:after:last-of-type`.

Alternatively, you could just usea little bit of extra JavaScript / jQuery to get things working:

```
$(".slideshow > img:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('.slideshow > img:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('.slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

Which will hide all slides, then fade in the slides one after another, and can be seen in the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#view-content").on("click", function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      if ($('#topic' + i).prop('checked')) {
        $('.topic' + i).show();
      } else {
        $('.topic' + i).hide();
      }
    }
    
    $(".slideshow > img:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() {
      $('.slideshow > img:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('.slideshow');
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

input[type=checkbox] {}

.topic {
  width: 200px;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
}

.view {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.selectall {
  display: none;
}

.slideshow {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Topics</h1>

<h4>Or choose from popular search terms: </h4>
<div class="row">
  <button type="button">term1</button>
  <button type="button">term2</button>
  <button type="button">term3</button>
  <button type="button">term4</button>
  <button type="button">term5</button>
  <button type="button">term6</button>
  <button type="button">term7</button>
  <button type="button">term8</button>
  <button type="button">term9</button>
  <button type="button">term10</button>
</div>

<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic1" />
      <label for="topic1">Topic 1</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic2" />
      <label for="topic2">Topic 2</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic3" />
      <label for="topic3">Topic 3</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic4" />
      <label for="topic4">Topic 4</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic5" />
      <label for="topic5">Topic 5</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic6" />
      <label for="topic6">Topic 6</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic7" />
      <label for="topic7">Topic 7</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic8" />
      <label for="topic8">Topic 8</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic9" />
      <label for="topic9">Topic 9</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic10" />
      <label for="topic10">Topic 10</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic11" />
      <label for="topic11">Topic 11</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic12" />
      <label for="topic12">Topic 12</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic13" />
      <label for="topic13">Topic 13</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic14" />
      <label for="topic14">Topic 14</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="checkbox" id="topic15" />
      <label for="topic15">Topic 15</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<button type="button" class="view" id="view-content">View Content</button>
<div class="slideshow">
  <img class="topic1 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/Kf2zBCB.jpg" />
  <img class="topic2 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/Sd44gRr.jpg" />
  <img class="topic3 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/5t6Qp5y.jpg" />
  <img class="topic4 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/5vyPC7P.jpg" />
  <img class="topic5 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/H400nzy.jpg" />
  <img class="topic6 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/MXVqtDe.jpg" />
  <img class="topic7 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic8 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic9 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic10 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic11 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic12 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic13 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic14 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
  <img class="topic15 selectall" src="https://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, that is kind of what I'm looking for. I'm going to use arrow buttons instead of having a time-based slideshow. With your code I noticed that the slideshow shows **all** the slides regardless of whether they've been checked by the user. The "next" slide will most likely be a different value each time depending on what topics the user checked, that's why I'm having trouble displaying one slide at a time. I don't know how to hide the rest and show them with next/prev buttons.